# ObjectInputStream .readObject() returning null?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, hashmap, objectinputstream

I'm a bit confuse, because I've done this a few times in the past and worked perfect, but now I'm getting printed *"HashMap is null"* and `NullPointerException` when trying to use the variable returned by `getMap()`.

Here is all the code, this class is used to save and load variable `HashMap<String, String> map`:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

/**
 *
 * @author None
 */
public class MapManager {
    private HashMap<String, String> map;
    private File mapFile;

    public MapManager(){
        map = new HashMap<>();
        mapFile = new File("map.dat");
    }

    //Gets the database from the computer
    public HashMap<String, String> getMap(){

        if(mapFile.exists()){
            try{
                FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(mapFile);
                ObjectInputStream objectIn = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
                map = (HashMap<String, String>)objectIn.readObject();
                if(map == null){
                    System.out.println("HashMap is null");
                }
                objectIn.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else{
            try{
                boolean databaseCreated = mapFile.createNewFile();
                System.out.println("Creating new HashMap");
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return map;
    }

    //Save the currend Database in a the computer
    public void saveMap(HashMap<String, String> map){        
       try{
           FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(mapFile);
           ObjectOutputStream objectOut = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
           objectOut.writeObject(map);
           System.out.println("HashMap has been saved");
           objectOut.close();
       }catch(Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: for some reason, without touching anything, just closing the IDE fixed everything.

Comment: Sample of mapfile content?

Comment: You haven't closed `fileOut`. Maybe it hasn't written the content yet. Add a statement to close it and try again

Comment: @janos - objectOut close will close fileOut.

Comment: do you get any exceptions?

Comment: if you use `createFile()` you won't be able to read this.  I would suggest not do this as it stores nothing.

Comment: your getMap() method creates an _empty file_ if one does not currently exist.  if you never _save_ the map, the next time you call getMap, you will attempt to read from an empty file.

Comment: @jtahlborn I have an ActionListener in my main JFrame for `windowClosing` that automatically calls `saveMap()` before finishing the app. Also, I tried to delete the file from my computer, so it creates a new one. Then, I fill a bit the `HashMap` with `.put()` method, but still getting NullPointException when I try to access map.

Comment: i would suggest opening your app in a debugger and tracing the execution.